# Is the height of a binary tree log2(n)

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, logarithm

Lets say we have an array with the length of `n=7`, the height of the tree should be `2`. I wouldn't count the height by the number of rows but connections between them. 
(I think that because in the heapsort algorithm the Siftdown Method says that the last row as a height of `0` it can travel and the row before can travel height of `1`, so `2` rows in a tree would allow height `1` to travel.)

So to get the height I would calculate `log2(allNodesInTheBottomRow)` which is `(n+1)/2`.

Is `log2((n+1)/2)` correct?.

Here, an example:

[image]

Comment: i dont think this is correct. log2((n+1)/2) = log2(n+1) - log2(2) =  log2(n+1) - 1. for n=2 it becomes log(2+1) - 1= log(3) - 1 = 1-1=0. but it should be 1 right?

Comment: Hmm I see ur point, my thought was for example in the tree that I linked are 4 nodes in the bottom row. We know that in the bottom row of every tree there are half of all existing nodes + 1 node, that's why log2((n+1)/2).

Comment: First you should read about types of Binary Tree. There can be Full Binary tree , Complete Binary tree, Perfect Binary tree etc. (types)[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-tree-set-3-types-of-binary-tree/] . So your assumption that ***bottom row of every tree there are half of all existing nodes + 1 node*** depends on the type of tree.

Answer (score 2):

In general it is not true that the height of a binary tree is `O(log n)`. Note that in the following image, both of these trees are valid binary trees:

[image: The image on the right is just an *unbalanced* binary tree]

Note that the tree on the right fulfills the property that the right child is larger than the root and is itself the root of a binary tree.

I think what you mean to say is that a *balanced* binary tree has height `O(log n)`. Note that the canonical definition of a balanced binary tree is a the binary tree on the given set of elements where the height is minimal (or in many cases, close to minimal - a constant factor away). It is straightforward to make the intuitive observation that this happens when each row is fully saturated (i.e. the tree is *complete* or *almost complete*).

Note that when the tree is fully saturated, the first row has `1` element, the second row has `2` elements, and the `ith` row has `2^(i-1)` elements. As a result, we have that if there are `n` elements, that `n = 2^(log n)`. This means that there are `O(log n)` rows as needed.

If you are looking for a precise function to compute the height rather than just an `O(log n)` bound, you simply round `n` up to the nearest power of `2` and then compute the log of that. For example, if `n=7`, the nearest power of `2` is `8` and `log(8) = 3` as needed. You can subtract by `1` at the end depending on your definition of height.

Comment: alright thanks, I was confused that log n isn't a round number